# Does your beer have a "house" flavor?

Tags: flavor, ingredients

I identify "house" flavor as a similar flavor that carries across several different styles of beer from the same brewery.

What parts of the brewing process or ingredients lend to "house" flavor the most?

What commercial breweries in your area, or in your experience have a distinct house flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think possible sources could include:
Water chemistry
Single house yeast
Affinity to one variety of bittering hop

In my area, shipyard brewing in Maine has been labelled as having a diacetyl (butter-like) house flavor.  Predominantly from the use of Ringwood Ale yeast.

Answer (score 4):

One brewery I have been to in Michigan called Hereford and Hops the house flavor is buttery diacetyl because he's not resting his beers long enough.

I have found that most "house flavors" have to do with the brewer being addicted to a single ingredient or technique that creates it.  Really, other than water chemistry (which can and should be adjusted anyway) most house flavor is really "house flaw".